# Play a sound with python

Tags: python

I am trying to play a sound at a certain altitude with my raspberry pi. I would use

`import winsound`

but I have no idea what I would use if it was on the pi. Would it remain the same?

Comment: possible duplicate of https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7088/playing-audio-files-with-python found by searching for "play a sound with python on raspberry pi"

Comment: AJCoder, please let us know if you think that the Q&A linked above is not answering your question sufficiently. Also [related](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/94207/19949) where I have come to enjoy the workings of `vlc` with python-bindings to do just that.

Comment: Example with GPIO and pygame here: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/recipes.html#gpio-music-box